# Horribly slow HDD to HDD write speeds after new HDD install

Tags: hard-drive, transfer

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.5.4-050504-generic x86_64)

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 4.56 TiB, 5000981078016 bytes, 9767541168 sectors
Disk model: ST5000LM000-2AN1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: CT480BX500SSD1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DE67E89B-9575-4882-8044-6A33894B923E

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624   3147775   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  3147776 937699327 934551552 445.6G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdc: 10.94 TiB, 12000138625024 bytes, 23437770752 sectors
Disk model: ST12000NM001G-2M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CC2F2B70-FE09-4BBF-9803-FFFE8C3C9049

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 23437768703 23437766656 10.9T Linux filesystem
```

Recently picked up a 12TB Seagate Exos HDD, and copied the contents of my 5TB drive to it, which took about 12 hours, fairly normal transfer speeds.

However all of a sudden the next day I'm getting atrocious transfer speeds from the 5TB to the 12TB, like sub 5Mb/s and I'm not sure where to start looking

Drives are mounted simply:

```
/dev/sdc1 /plexmedia ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/sda /torrent ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Both formatted to ext4

`lsblk -f`:

```
sda                       ext4              3d82fdd8-9b7a-4e79-a6fb-9c2fcb2dec21      4.3T     1% /torrent
sdb
├─sdb1                    vfat              6C8A-8802                               503.2M     2% /boot/efi
├─sdb2                    ext4              337a91bb-7a97-44be-b837-74fc530452f2    723.8M    19% /boot
└─sdb3                    LVM2_member       YJZlfR-mKCw-dVfH-PN4T-xZam-idSX-nbvHOt
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4              5c6dea55-f0b1-4693-8456-516a42e80a74    159.1G    14% /
sdc
└─sdc1                    ext4              247d5978-83a2-42b3-9f75-0d9c61803826        6T    40% /plexmedia
```

I'm also using the patched `cp` from GNU coreutils v 8.32

Performance varies wildly:

```
1 files (  5.0 GiB) copied in 1413.9 seconds (  3.6 MiB/s).
1 files (  7.2 GiB) copied in 181.2 seconds ( 40.7 MiB/s).
1 files (  5.7 GiB) copied in 71.2 seconds ( 82.4 MiB/s).
```

Comment: `/dev/sda /torrent ext4 defaults 0 0`! Is that drive partitioned? If so, Why mount the drive itself instead of the partition on the drive? Please add the output of `lsblk -f`

Comment: Search this site for "slow copy" and see many suggestions.  What copy command did you use to move 5TB of data in 12hrs -- normal copy speed of about 115MB/sec?  Many people would be interested in that.

Comment: @Raffa I guess I didn't partition the 5TB drive, it is just directly mounted.

Comment: @ubfan1 I should clarify that there was 4.3TB on the 5TB drive, so 4.3 over ~12 hours

Comment: How is that even possible? Un-partitioned drives are unusable and usable drives that show no partitions must have problems. This drive must have had at least one partition then something wrong happened and caused the partition to not show anymore. This is not normal.

Comment: @Raffa surprising as it may sound but I believe drives can be used without partitioning / partition table. Not like I would recommend it.

Comment: This is not exactly the same / every-day use-case, but here they copy the linux image to the USB drive while mounting the device directly: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_medium `cp path/to/archlinux.iso /dev/sdx` I happen to know this because this is how I made my live-USB.

Comment: @Levente That is not using the drive without partitioning. That is recreating / imaging an already [functional filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) to the USB drive. This can as well be done with other filesystems. If you use `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=32M` for example, it will clone drive `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb` with all the partitions and filesystems intact so as if `/dev/sdb` were partitioned and formatted. But AFAIK, no drive can be used without partitioning and formatting.

Comment: @Raffa not having a partition table was definitely the issue, see my response comment. Partitioned and now I'm getting expected file copy performance. I didn't even know it was possible to use a drive like that!

Comment: @squeekwull Well done!

Comment: @Raffa unfortunately my issue has not been solved :/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Not actually solved. I can be cruising along great, copying multiple GB worth of large files, getting solid xfer rates, around 130MiB/s, and then performance completely tanks, rates lower than 5.0MiB/s!

```
1 files (  7.8 GiB) copied in 2084.7 seconds (  3.8 MiB/s).
```

It seems like the disk cache fills up and just takes an extremely long time to flush? I'm not sure, but this is getting pretty annoying!

@Raffa SOLVED: It appears to be user error on my part (usually is!) and I didn't have a partition setup for /dev/sda. Added an ext4 partition, and now `cp` from /dev/sda1 to /dev/sdc1 is as fast as you would assume given this `hdparm` output:

```
[2021-01-10 19:17:55] sean@muth-dev / λ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   30588 MB in  1.99 seconds = 15396.57 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 196 MB in  3.00 seconds =  65.24 MB/sec

[2021-01-10 19:18:34] sean@muth-dev / λ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 Timing cached reads:   30404 MB in  1.99 seconds = 15305.23 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 728 MB in  3.00 seconds = 242.54 MB/sec
```

Recent file transfer:

```
1 files (  4.1 GiB) copied in 2.4 seconds (  1.7 GiB/s).
```